# New to GCC - running a array insertion gives me different output locally than on online compiler

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop, gcc

I am going through a TuturialsPoint algorithm and trying to run the C code with GCC. Would anyone know why my local output would be different that what is produced by an online C compiler?

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int LA[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 8};
    int item = 10, k = 3, n = 5;
    int i = 0, j = n;

    printf("The original array elements are :\n");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("LA[%d] = %d \n", i, LA[i]);
    }

    n = n + 1;

    while (j >= k)
    {
        LA[j + 1] = LA[j];
        j = j - 1;
    }

    LA[k] = item;

    printf("The array elements after insertion :\n");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("LA[%d] = %d \n", i, LA[i]);
    }
}
```

Expected output (from online gcc compiler)

```
The original array elements are :
LA[0] = 1 
LA[1] = 3 
LA[2] = 5 
LA[3] = 7 
LA[4] = 8 
The array elements after insertion :
LA[0] = 1 
LA[1] = 3 
LA[2] = 5 
LA[3] = 10 
LA[4] = 7 
LA[5] = 8
```

My local output:

```
The original array elements are :
LA[0] = 1
LA[1] = 3
LA[2] = 5
LA[3] = 7
LA[4] = 8
The array elements after insertion :
LA[0] = 1
LA[1] = 3
LA[2] = 5
LA[3] = 7
LA[4] = 8
LA[5] = 6
```

I am using gcc version 8.2.0 (MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-5)

Comment: Your array has only place for 5 elements. Assigning to the 6th element is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Kevin Camp This statement  n = n + 1; does not make the array larger.

Comment: When I change to LA[j] = LA[j-1] I also get unexpected answer

Comment: I thought it looked wrong - just following their example, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You defined an array of exactly 5 elements.

```
int LA[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 8};
```

So the valid range of indices to access elements of the array is `[0, 5)`.

This array may not be enlarged. So using an index equal to or greater than 5 results in access and overwriting the memory beyond the array.

You need initially to define the array with the number of elements that allows to insert new elements apart from the 5 explicitly initialized elements.

What you mean is something like the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };

    int a[N] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 8 };

    size_t n = 0;

    while ( a[n] != 0 ) ++n;

    printf( "The original array elements are :" );
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    int item = 10;
    size_t pos = 3;

    size_t j = n;

    if ( pos < j )
    {
        for ( ; j != pos; j-- )
        {
            a[j] = a[j-1];
        }
    }

    a[j] = item;

    ++n;

    printf( "The array elements after insertion : " );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
The original array elements are :1 3 5 7 8 
The array elements after insertion : 1 3 5 10 7 8
```

Note: This code snippet

```
    if ( pos < j )
    {
        for ( ; j != pos; j-- )
        {
            a[j] = a[j-1];
        }
    }
```

can be substituted for this loop

```
for ( ; pos < j; j-- )
{
    a[j] = a[j-1];
}
```